# Updating table and setting the field values to the result of a left join

Tags: sql, ms-access, ddl

I have a table Sales with the field Vendor ("Company A", "Company B", "Trader X"),  and I have made a separate table called Vendors with two fields: VendorID and VendorName.

I want to delete the Vendor field in the table Sales and replace it with a VendorID field and fill the fill the field with the corresponding VendorIDs. In other words replace the names of the vendors in the Sales table with their ID from the Vendors table.

I have tried numerous solutions but they do not work. Here is one that I think will work. Some entries in the Sales table do not have any Vendors listed. There are 203 entries and the left join, when run on its own, returns all 203 vendors and the appropriate null values.

```
Update Sales
Set Sales.VendorID = (Select VendorID From Vendors v Left Join Sales s on 
v.VendorName = s.Vendor);
```

When I run this I get a dialog box asking :

> Enter Parameter Value

Or I get the error message :

> Operation must use an updateable query

I am using MS Access 2016.

Comment: Just want to be clear. Since you need to update the value in column vendor_id of Sales table, shouldn't the subquery join be written as v.vendor_name=s.vendors, rather than their id?

Sorry, I do not have much idea about MS Access, I am unsure about the error message.

Comment: Correct. My apologies. I've been working on this problem for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't need a subquery, you could just use the `UPDATE ... JOIN ... SET` syntax, like :

```
UPDATE sales AS s
INNER JOIN Vendors AS v ON v.VendorName = s.Vendor
SET s.VendorID = v.VendorID
```

Comment: I changed INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN and was able to do what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @Albert : `LEFT JOIN` will cause `sales` records whose `Vendor` cannot be found in `Vendors.VendorName` to be set to `NULL` is it what you want ?

Comment: Yes as I stated in my question.